# C++: Using operator of two intrinsic types as a function object

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming

I have a vector-like class that contains an array of objects of type `"T"`, and I want to implement 4 arithmetic operators, which will apply the operation on each item:

```
// Constructors and other functions are omitted for brevity.
template<class T, unsigned int D>
class Vector {

public:
    // Add a value to each item: naive implementation.
    void operator += (const T&) {
        for (int i = 0; i < D; ++i) {
            data[i] += value;
        }
    }
    void operator -= (const T&) { ... }
    void operator *= (const T&) { ... }
    void operator /= (const T&) { ... }

private:
    T items[D];
};
```

Because operators will contain the same boilerplate code (looping over every element and applying appropriate operation), I thought I could generalize it:

```
template<class T, unsigned int D>
class Vector {

public:
    void operator += (const T& value) { do_for_each(???, value); }
    void operator -= (const T& value) { do_for_each(???, value); }
    void operator *= (const T& value) { do_for_each(???, value); }
    void operator /= (const T& value) { do_for_each(???, value); }

private:
    void
    do_for_each(std::binary_function<void, T, T>& op, T value) {
        std::for_each(data, data + D, std::bind2nd(op, value));
    }

    T data[D];
};
```

Now, the problem is, how do I pass an operator that takes two intrinsic types and returns `void` to `do_for_each`, as depicted in the example above? C++ does not let me do this trick for intrinsic types (`"T::operator+="` will not work if `"T"` is `"int"`).

Comment: You might want to fix `data` vs `items` ...

Comment: Questions like this are why friends don't let friends overload operators

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should really return a reference from your operator+=, since you can later use them to implement operator+, operator- and so on. I will change that accordingly.

Also, your do_for_each has to be a template, since it has to know the precise type of the function object, as binary function objects are not polymorph classes. For the actual operation, you want to use `std::transform`:

```
template<class T, unsigned int D>
class Vector {

public:
    Vector& operator += (const T& value) { 
        do_for_each(std::plus<T>(), value); 
        return *this;
    }

    Vector& operator -= (const T& value) { 
        do_for_each(std::minus<T>(), value); 
        return *this;
    }

    Vector& operator *= (const T& value) { 
        do_for_each(std::multiplies<T>(), value);
        return *this; 
    }

    Vector& operator /= (const T& value) { 
        do_for_each(std::divides<T>(), value); 
        return *this;
    }

private:
    template<typename BinFun>
    void do_for_each(BinFun op, const T& value) {
        std::transform(data, data + D, data, std::bind2nd(op, value));
    }

    T data[D];
};
```

[std::transform](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/transform.html) will just pass each element to the function object, and assigns the result back to the iterator given as the third argument.

Comment: I was just in the process of writing the exact same thing! :)  Cheers, +1!

Comment: You should return a const reference from the operators, so that doing this (which is really hard to read/figure out) is not possible: (v += v2) -= v3

Comment: SoapBox: i don't see particular reasons to forbid that. Also, when you return non-const, you do what most don't do. This strives against principle of least surprise. It's perfectly reasonable to do f(a += b); for example.

Comment: SoapBox: while returning a const ref there is basicially just a matter of taste, returning a const object for operator+-*/ will actually slow down performance in c++1x. Since then the temporary returned cannot be moved anymore: it has to be copied then (since it's const it cannot bind to T&&)

Answer (score 2):

You should really have a look at [Boost Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/utility/operators.htm), a header-only library that really simplifies creating orthogonal and consistent arithmetic operator overloads.

Specifically: you might find that deriving from `boost::operators::integer_arithmatic<T>` saves you a lot of the repetition of this class.

Answer (score 1):

I think litb is on the correct track and answered the exact question.
But I think this is the wrong solution.

I would rather not use the do_for_each() but rather use the std::transform() directly:

```
template<class T, unsigned int D>
class Vector 
{

  public:
    Vector& operator += (const T& value) { 
        std::transform(data, data + D, data, std::bind2nd(std::plus<T>(),value)); 
        return *this;
    }

    Vector& operator -= (const T& value) { 
        std::transform(data, data + D, data, std::bind2nd(std::minus<T>(),value)); 
        return *this;
    }

    Vector& operator *= (const T& value) { 
        std::transform(data, data + D, data, std::bind2nd(std::multiplies<T>(),value));
        return *this; 
    }

    Vector& operator /= (const T& value) { 
        std::transform(data, data + D, data, std::bind2nd(std::divides<T>(),value)); 
        return *this;
    }

  private:
    T data[D];
};
```